# Why is the spark task running on a single node?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I  have installed a Spark cluster. It has 4 nodes, but when I run the SparkPi example on the cluster, there is only one node run. How do I solve it?

Comment: You have to give more details about your configuration per example and some error logs

Comment: I  think my configure may have some errors, I only set the slave file, and spark-env.sh, what  other files should I need to configure?

Comment: What do you mean by slave file? Spark has to run on top of a distributed computing infrastructure, what is your using?

Comment: I  have four nodes, one runs master and others run worker.

Comment: I agree that seeing the configuration and log outputs would make it easier to help. But their lack actually makes for a more generic question. It is like an FAQ entry. I think this can be quite useful, as I'm sure others will find themselves in the same situation. "Why is it running on a single node?" I'd rather improve the question than close it.

Comment: sorry,my english writing is not well, so sometimes I can not express thing I want to say.

Answer (score 11):

One possibility is, you are **running the example in local mode**. That is, the example does not use the cluster at all. It is easy to verify this: stop the Spark master and see if the example still works.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html describes how to run the example.

```
bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master local \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  100
```

You need to replace `local` with something like `spark://spark-master.example.com:7077`.

Another explanation could be that **only one worker has connected** to the master for some reason. Or, the **master only assigns limited resources** to the application for some reason. You can check both of these on the master UI. (`http://spark-master.example.com:8080/`)

Finally, it can be that **your data is split into too few partitions**, and they are all picked up by a single machine. In the above example, `100` is the number of partitions. If you omit it, it defaults to `2`. If your workers have 2 or more cores, it is likely that one of them will pick up both partitions. You can see if this is the case when you look at the executed stages on the application UI. (`http://localhost:4040/stages`) The solution is to increase the number of partitions.

Comment: ./bin/run-example SparkPi 10000  spark://master:7077   I use  this command to  run the example, and from 4040, I can only find one executor.

Comment: Good, you're not in local mode then! I've thought a bit more and added a few more possible explanations to the answer. Please take a look and see if one of them helps!