# Dividing tasks among Spark workers

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, apache-spark

I am running my program on a Spark cluster. But when I look at the UI while the job is running, I see that only one worker does most of the tasks. My cluster has one master and 4 workers where the master is also a worker.

I want my task to complete as quickly as possible and I believe that if the number of tasks were to be divided equally among the workers, the job will be completed faster.

Is there any way I can customize this?

```
System.setProperty("spark.default.parallelism","20")
val sc = new SparkContext("spark://10.100.15.2:7077","SimpleApp","/home/madhura/spark",List("hdfs://master:54310/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar"))
val dRDD = sc.textFile("hdfs://master:54310/in*",10)
val keyval=dRDD.coalesce(100,true).mapPartitionsWithIndex{(ind,iter) => iter.map(x => process(ind,x.trim().split(' ').map(_.toDouble),q,m,r))}
```

I tried this but it did not help.

Comment: Yes it's very easy in spark to change the parallelism, usually when you post a question you have to show some effort though, what type of code are you running?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167194/why-is-the-spark-task-running-on-a-single-node, sounds like the same question.

Comment: @Daniel:Not really. I am sure it's running on cluster mode as when I look into my UI, some of the tasks are done by the other workers. I just want to distribute the tasks uniformly.